# Unhandled rejection MongoError: cannot connect to server in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I got `Unhandled rejection MongoError: cannot connect to server` when run my meanjs project.

Previously was running fine but when update `nodejs 5.11.1`, `mongodb 3.2.6`,`"mongoose": "^4.4.16"` and `"connect-mongo": "^1.1.0",` then this error getting.

> Unhandled rejection MongoError: cannot connect to server
>           at Collection.listIndexes (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1750:11)
>           at indexInformation (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1625:25)
>           at Db.indexInformation (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1589:44)
>           at ensureIndex (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1082:8)
>           at Db.ensureIndex (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1058:44)
>           at ensureIndex (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1820:13)
>           at Collection.ensureIndex (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1808:44)
>           at MongoStore.setAutoRemoveAsync (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:123:40)
>           at MongoStore.handleNewConnectionAsync (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:116:18)
>           at MongoStore (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:95:26)
>           at module.exports (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/config/express.js:101:10)
>           at Object. (/home/shaishab/Project/Open-Source/BS-Commerce/server.js:31:38)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)

in config file code

```
var session = require('express-session'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connect('dbUrl');
app.use(session({
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true,
        secret: config.sessionSecret,
        store: new MongoStore({
            db: db.connection.db,
            collection: config.sessionCollection
        })
}));
```

Can any one help me ?

Comment: Can you check if mongodb is running with the specified connection string?

Comment: from mongo shell I can access my db @Astro

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Finally I got where error occurred!!** I post this answer because of it may will help others.

Problem occurred when update `mongoose` and `connect-mongo` version.

need to update:

```
MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
```

and

```
app.use(session({
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true,
        secret: config.sessionSecret,
        store: new MongoStore({
            mongooseConnection: db.connection,
            collection: config.sessionCollection
        })
    }));
```

main problem was in `MongoStore({db: db.connection.db` instead of use

```
db: db.connection.db
```

now using

```
mongooseConnection: db.connection
```

that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As I did not have a `db variable`, my solution was:

```
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/chester');

app.use(session({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new mongoStore({mongooseConnection: connection})
  }));
```

hope it helps